# Shifting (Not Freezing) Date/Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm looking for a way to shift the browser's `Date` to a specified one without freezing time. Let's pretend I have some function `shiftDate()` which does just that. The following outlines the behavior I'm seeking:

```
// Here's the current time.
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1391109350382
//
// Now let's call the function to shift/travel back in time and _immediately_
// check the time afterwards
shiftDate('2014-01-01');
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534400000
// 
// Now let's wait 1111 ms and then check the time again
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534401111
//
// Let's wait another 1111 ms
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534402222
//
// Let's shift/travel back in time once more
shiftDate('2014-01-01');
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534400000
//
// Then wait 1111 ms again
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534401111
//
// And wait 1111 ms again
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534402222
```

Notice time keeps ticking after each shift. Most solutions that I've found entirely freeze time through a mock or stub of some sort. However, freezing time is not an appropriate solution: doing so disrupts other time-dependent features such as animations. Below is an example, which freezes time:

```
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1391109350382
var oldDate = Date;
Date = function() { return new oldDate('2014-01-01'); };
var testDate = new Date();
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534400000
// Wait 1111 ms, ten minutes, or an hour: time will never change
new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534400000
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting the native `Date`, and then calling it again with `new` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "travelling to specified start time"? Travel with what? Why does it not work by simply not using a `frozenDate`?

Comment: Freezing time stops the clock from ticking. I'm looking to travel back to a specified time, but allow time to continue progressing from that point. I've updated the question with more specific examples.

Comment: I would like to help you but couldn't get what you are trying to do.  Sorry :(  Would you consider to update your question with more details .  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it! The trick is to keep track of the time change within a new `Date` prototype. Here's a rough implementation:

```
function shiftDate(date) {
  window.trueDate = window.trueDate || Date;
  var trueStart = new trueDate().getTime();
  var shiftedStart = new Date(date).getTime();
  Date = function() {
    var timeChange = new trueDate() - trueStart;
    return new trueDate(shiftedStart + timeChange);
  }
}
```

And here's a simple test:

```
shiftDate('2014-01-01')
testDate = new Date();
setInterval(function(){
 console.log(new Date().toString());
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Momentjs for handy date and time manipulation.

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // Let's shift/travel back in time once
> shiftDate('2014-01-01');
> new Date().getTime(); //=> 1388534400000
> ```

I'm not sure why you don't simply do `new Date('2014-01-01').getTime();` in your custom, shifted logic?

---

However, you can get the desired behaviour with the following function:

```
function shiftDate(to) {
    var realDate = Date;
    Date = function frozenDate() {
        Date = realDate;
        return new Date(to);
    };
}
```

When you call `shiftDate`, the next - and only the next - call to `Date` will yield a date from a confused timeline.

Comment: see also [Monkeypatch the JavasScript date object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21591320/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any way you can change the date objects internal time pointer (if you want to call it that) without going deep into the OS. I think you'd have to write your own little library, similar to this:

```
var myDate = function(dateStr){

  var initTime = new Date().getTime()
  var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
  var myDateTime = dateObj.getTime();

  // subtract the init time from the time this method is called
  // to get a difference, then add it to your "old" time to get 
  // the updated millisecond value
  this.getTime = function(){
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var dif = currentTime - initTime;
    return myDateTime + dif;
  };

};
```

You could of course get fancy with the methods and implement all of the native Date object methods.