# Monkeypatch the JavasScript date object

Tags: javascript, datetime

I know that this a crazy hack but curious about it anyhow.  We have an environment that has the wrong system time and we cannot set it to the correct time.  It's specialized hardware so we cannot change the system time.  We do however have a service that gives us the correct current time.  Our issue is that a bunch of ssl and token signing libraries break because they are getting the wrong datetime from the javascript Date object ( since we have the wrong system time).

What's the way to monkeypatch the Date object's constructor so that we can feed it the correct time to initialize with so that all subsequent calls to Date(), Date.toString(), etc... in the dependent libraries will return our new method that returns the correct non-system time?

Will this work?

```
var oldDate = Date;
Date = function(){
    return new oldDate(specialCallToGetCorrectTime()); 
}
Date.prototype = oldDate.prototype;
```

Comment: Can't you just use `Date('1/1/2014');` ? Maybe I am not getting the requirement right. Can you clarify the question more.

Comment: What sort of "service" are you using to get the correct time?

Comment: Also it seems to me that putting more effort into correcting a ridiculous situation like a bad server clock would be a better use of time.

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries and what not in node.js that rely on the correct date from calling new Date() .  Things like https and aws libraries that need to sign tokens.  These things all break with the wrong system time.  I can't go into all the libraries and hunt down every instance where they call Date() .  We have a special call that lets us get the correct time from a channel on the specialized hardware that we are running on.. this hardware also prevents us from setting the system time to something correct.

Comment: You will have hands full of more mess. Why? Because in browsers you have Window.Date. But in Node.js there is no Window object. So you are looking at multiple monkey patches.

Comment: I think you would be better of trying to find where in the source code Node.js gets the system time, and add whatever you need to add there instead of trying to rewrite the Date object in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this work?

No, since it does not respect arguments given to your new `Date` function or whether it was called as a constructor vs not. Also you forgot to fix `Date.now()`. You still will need to get those right:

```
Date = (function (oldDate, oldnow) {
    function Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms) {
         var res, l = arguments.length;
         if (l == 0) {
             res = new oldDate(Date.now());
         } else if (l == 1) {
             res = new oldDate(year); // milliseconds since epoch, actually
         } else {
             res = new oldDate(
                 year,
                 month,
                 l > 2 ? date : 1,
                 l > 3 ? hours : 0,
                 l > 4 ? minutes : 0,
                 l > 5 ? seconds : 0,
                 l > 6 ? ms : 0)
         }
         if (this instanceof Date) {
             return res;                 
         } else {
             return res.toString();
         }
    }
    Date.prototype = oldDate.prototype; // required for instanceof checks
    Date.now = function() {
         return oldnow() + offset; // however the system time was wrong
    };
    Date.parse = oldDate.parse;
    Date.UTC = oldDate.UTC;
    return Date;
})(Date, Date.now);
```

Comment: @Koka: If you want to get rid of the required `new` (which this monkeypatching sucessfully fakes), omit that `if (this instanceof Date)` test and always return `res` instead of the string.

Comment: ooops now i looked into that

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out in the latest Chrome, Firefox, and IE, and it is allowed. I'm not convinced this is better than just fixing the system time (surely it *can* be fixed), but the approach is doable.

Comment: If you tried it out, where is the answer? I was expecting to see someone changing the time reported from Date, and still having pass al the arguments along and be able to be called with "new" etc ?

Comment: unfortunately the system time is locked on the specialized hardware that we are running on.

Comment: Whatever `specialCallToGetCorrectTime` returns should work, provided that it's compatible with what the default `Date` implementation allows. The code that @MonkeyBonkey already allows a date to be created with `Date()` or `new Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided the implementation allows you to redefine window.Date

(It's polite to wrap this sort of thing in a closure)