# Is it possible to trick JS Date() into returning an alternate present time?

Tags: javascript, date, browser, time

I'm developing an app that involves a copious number of time variables, and uses the work-week for a rotation of functionality. Without having foreseen the issue of testing the week-day features during the weekend, I built all of the app's time features on the current time without modifiers in place.

I'm using the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library, and Moment uses `Date()` to get the **current time**.

I know I can:

- manipulate the dates/moments in my script accordingly
- input a date object into every place that I've created a new Moment in the code and manipulate that date: `var n = Date(past/present/future); Moment(n);`

However, these solutions are potentially ***more*** time-consuming than just not working on the app during the weekend.

**So my question:**

Is it possible to trick/manipulate `JS Date()` into returning an alternate present time, either through browser manipulation or code? If so, how is it done in one of the major web browsers or with code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monkeypatch the JavasScript date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591078/monkeypatch-the-javasscript-date-object) (for the purpose of testing, this even seems legitimate)

Comment: Have you tried changing the system clock?

Comment: You can always manipulate the browser or system clock, yes.

Comment: @Bergi I would hardly call that a duplicate, on account of its ineffective / slang title. If anyone were to search for the solution to this particular question on the site, they would likely not use "Monkeypatch" in their query.

Comment: @Andre Well, I'd still like to be able to see the real time on my system...

Comment: You're asking to "*trick JS Date() into returning an alternate present time*", and that's just what my answer on that question does. Whether the other question is oddly titled should not matter (and I didn't say you should have found it by searching - I have found it for you from my memory).

Comment: Right @Bergi I understand that, but it would be difficult for you to introduce all future askers to that question from memory. I would think that the possibility of a question being found is of some importance. Try searching SO for the answer to this question without the word "monkeypatch" ...

Comment: Well, from now on they will hopefully find this question and then be directed by my link to an existing answer - that's how "closing as a duplicate" works :-)