# Monkey patch JavaScript new Date()

Tags: javascript, date

I need to monkey patch JavaScript's date object. The only thing I need to change is `new Date()`, which I need to always return the same date.

There is a similar question about changing the date via an offset, but Im wondering if I do the same thing with less code?:
[Monkeypatch the JavasScript date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591078/monkeypatch-the-javasscript-date-object)

Modifying the code from the question above I have a solution that does work with this:

```
Date = (function(oldDate) {
    /**
     * @return {string}
     */
    function Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms) {
      let res;
      const l = arguments.length;
      if (l == 0) {
        res = new oldDate(Date.now());
      } else if (l == 1) {
        res = new oldDate(year); // milliseconds since epoch, actually
      } else {
        res = new oldDate(
          year,
          month,
          l > 2 ? date : 1,
          l > 3 ? hours : 0,
          l > 4 ? minutes : 0,
          l > 5 ? seconds : 0,
          l > 6 ? ms : 0,
        );
      }
      if (this instanceof Date) {
        return res;
      }
      return res.toString();
    }
    Date.prototype = oldDate.prototype; // required for instanceof checks
    Date.now = function() {
      return 1570705688585; // HERE I REUTRN A FIXED DATE
    };
    Date.parse = oldDate.parse;
    Date.UTC = oldDate.UTC;
    return Date;
  })(Date, Date.now);
```

Looking at these docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

It seems `Date.now` has a pollyfill you can use:

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```

I tried this but it had no affect:

```
  Date.now = function now() {
    return 1570705688585;
  };
```

Comment: [Seems to work for me](https://jsbin.com/yogaqemomu/1/edit?js,console) - when I run your code and call `new Date()` it gives me `2019-10-10T11:08:08.585Z` which is what that Unix timestamp resolves to.

Comment: @VLAZ when you say my code do you mean the first or last block?

Comment: I've added a link to JSBin that shows it in action. It's the first block of code, I used.

Comment: Yes I know that it works "I have a solution that does work with this", however I was wondering if a much shorter version would also work.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've misread your question, then.

Comment: Don't monkey patch if you can avoid it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to just change `Date.now` as the constructor might not invoke that method. However, you can make the patch shorter by directly copying all properties and only overwriting `Date.now` and the zero argument constructor:

```js
//keep for testing
const OriginalDateConstructor = Date;

Date = (function(oldDate) {
  function Date(...args) {
    if (args.length === 0) {
      //override the zero argument constructor
      return new oldDate(Date.now())
    } 
    
    //else delegate to the original constructor
    return new oldDate(...args);
  }
  //copy all properties from the original date, this includes the prototype
  const propertyDescriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(oldDate);
  Object.defineProperties(Date, propertyDescriptors);
  
  //override Date.now
  Date.now = function() {
    return 1570705688585;
  };
  
  return Date;
})(Date);

console.log("same prototype", Object.getPrototypeOf(Date) === Object.getPrototypeOf(OriginalDateConstructor))
console.log("no argument", new Date());
console.log("single argument - zero", new Date(0));
console.log("single argument - non-zero", (new Date(new OriginalDateConstructor("2019-01-01").getTime())));
console.log("passing ISO string", new Date("2019-06-01"));
console.log("passing year, month", new Date(2019, 09));
console.log("passing year, month, day", new Date(2019, 09, 15));
console.log("passing year, month, day, hour", new Date(2019, 09, 15, 10));
console.log("passing year, month, day, hour, minutes", new Date(2019, 07, 15, 10, 30));
console.log("passing year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds", new Date(2019, 07, 15, 10, 30, 45));
console.log("passing in a date", new Date(new Date("2019-03-01")))

console.log("conversion to number", +new Date("2019-06-01T12:00"))
console.log("implicit conversion to string", "" + new Date("2019-06-01T12:00"))
```